# Where can I find the text of rule that talks about responsibility of PIC on avoiding collision from fixed obstacles?

Tags: incidents, rules-of-the-air

This question relates to Qatari 777 collision with pole on taxiway. I know that in this case PIC is responsible. But I can't find the text of that on annex or docs. Can you help me to find it on annex?

Comment: I doubt that there is a specific rule forbidding you from hitting obstacles, because as you said, you know the PIC is responsible. Plus it's one of those self punishing acts... Something like "operating in a careless and reckless manner" is probably the closest you will get.  Is that what you are looking for?  And what jurisdiction?

Comment: I thought that there is a rule states that the controller has no responsibility for avoiding aircraft from fixed obstacles on maneuvering area. Or sth like that.

Comment: Perhaps it was low vis and the controller cleared them onto a taxiway that wasn't appropriate for their wingspan?  As it's been pointed out, these things are investigated and there are generally multiple root causes.  If you look purely at the regs to assign blame you will miss the big picture and be ineffective at implementing corrective action.

Comment: Maybe it's better to wait for official reports. But I heard that everyday 777s taxi using this taxiway.

Comment: If you are interested in knowing the cause, then yes.  Just not sure what the existence of a “rule” might contribute to our understanding of the situation.

Comment: As I said, I was just looking for the text of the rule that I wrote it up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could have been better to provide information about the incident for us to rely, so then provide correct assessment.

Such incidents requires an investigation, first officer's claims, accuracy of the airport chart update in the pilot's *Manual of Electronic Flight Bags*, and recording of the ground frequency at the time..

Although, in general the weight gets put on the PIC (Pilot In Command)'s responsibilities, to watch for foreign objects and terrain, collision and even complete procedures, regardless of ATC or Ground control clearance,

> ANNEX VII (Part-NCO) SUBPART A: GENERAL REQUIREMENTS
>
> GM1 NCO.GEN.115 Taxiing of aeroplanes
>
> SAFETY-CRITICAL ACTIVITY
>
> (a) Taxiing should be treated as a safety-critical activity due to the
> risks related to the movement of the aeroplane and the potential for a
> catastrophic event on the ground.
>
> (b) Taxiing is a high-workload phase of flight that requires the full
> attention of the pilot-in-command.

But..

There are also responsibilities of the Ground controls to provide correct information that, if it was proven that they were giving false info or unsafe advisory in an overlapping manner, they can be accused of mishandling. In fact there are Laws set by ICAO for that when they receive their training, they are  :

> TWR ATM 10.6.1 Predict positions of aircraft in the aerodrome traffic
> and taxi circuits.
>
> TWR AGA 2.2.2 Describe taxiway
>
> BASIC LAWB 5.7.1 Describe the general design and layout of an
> aerodrome.
>
> Refer to this link :
> https://www.icao.int/sam/documents/2016-cbt/10056_draft_en.pdf

Investigation and information is necessary to assess this.

Comment: Thanks sir. The annex part of your answer is what I want.